# Mostrar letras griegas en las etiquetas de la gráfica

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-2.x

Estoy haciendo pruebas de bondad de ajuste de distribuciones de probabilidad para datos aleatorios dados. Para complementar creo gráficos de este estilo:

[image: Distribución Normal Estandar]

Pero me gustaría poder indicar la media y la varianza de la distribución usando sus letras griegas (mu y sigma cuadrado). ¿Es posible hacer eso en Matplotlib para obtener un gráfico con etiquetas como el siguiente?

[image: Imagen de distribuciones normales de wikipedia]

Estoy usando matplotlib y scipy, mi código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
mu, sigma = 0, 1.0 # media y desvio estandar
datos = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000) #creando muestra de datos
x=np.linspace(-4,4,num=1000)
y=st.norm.pdf(x,0,1)

plt.plot(x,y,'r')
# histograma de distribución normal.
plt.hist(datos, 30,color='c',histtype='bar',cumulative=False,edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.7,density=True,label="Datos")
plt.plot(x,y,'r--',label="PDF distribucion Normal ")
plt.ylim(0,0.5)
plt.ylabel('frequencia')
plt.xlabel('valores')
plt.title('Histograma - Variable aleatoria normal')
plt.legend(loc="upper right") 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Trabajo en IDE Spyder usando python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

Para especificar el carácter lo más simple y legible es que uses literales de cadena unicode. Usa UTF-8 por ejemplo como codificación para el script y recuerda [especificar al inicio del script](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) la codificación del código fuente al intérprete.

Una cosa muy importante a tener en cuenta es que la fuente usada por defecto por Matplotlib para las etiquetas tiene que soportar estos caracteres. Si en tu caso esto no ocurre (mostrara el típico carácter de reemplazo, por ejemplo `□` en su lugar) [especifica una fuente](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/font_family_rc_sgskip.html) disponible en el sistema que si tenga soporte para ese conjunto de caracteres:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st


rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['DejaVu Sans', 'Tahoma']


mu, sigma = 0, 1.0 # media y desvio estandar
datos = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000) #creando muestra de datos
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, num=1000)
y = st.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)


plt.plot(x, y, 'r--', label=(u"μ={}, σ²={}".format(mu, sigma)))
plt.legend(loc="upper right") 
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar expresiones matemáticas más complejas recordar que [Matplotlib permite el uso de LaTeX](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, sus soluciones se complementan muy bien :D un saludos a todos desde Chile  y gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 3):

Matplotlib se integra bien con las fórmulas LaTeX. Si la fórmula es lo bastante simple (como en tu caso) el propio motor de matplotlib trata de renderizarla. Si es más compleja delegará esa labor el LaTeX (lo que complica las cosas, pues necesitarías instalar también LaTeX).

En este caso la fórmula es sencilla, por lo que puedes usar este mecanismo. En cualquier lugar donde matplotlib espera una cadena (para las etiquetas de la leyenda, o los ejes, o el título de la gráfica, etc), la cadena puede contener una fórmula LaTeX encerrada entre signos dólar. LaTeX te da acceso a todas las letras griegas, así como a exponentes, subíndices, fracciones, sumatorios, y muchas cosas más. Ya que las macros de LaTeX usan el carácter `\` y éste es especial dentro de una cadena en python, hay que duplicarlo.

En este caso sería así (adaptando el [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/168006/7123) de [FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

mu, sigma = 0, 1.0 # media y desvio estandar
datos = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000) #creando muestra de datos
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, num=1000)
y = st.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)


plt.plot(x, y, 'r--', label=("$\\mu$={}, $\\sigma^2$={}".format(mu, sigma)))
plt.legend(loc="upper right") 
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]